# SubSonic edit class problem

Tags: c#, subsonic

I'm having a very odd issue with SubSonic where when I edit a class the database isn't being updated, even when I delete it and regenerate it.

Example: Simple class

```
public class Customer {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

Customer c = new Customer() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = "Toaster" };

var repo = new SimpleRepository("CustomerTest", 
    SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
repo.Add(c);
```

If I run this code it works perfectly, creates a table "Customer" and inserts the row for the toaster. However if I decide to change my Customer class to:

```
public class Customer {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set;}
}
```

And run the same code adding a value for the Cost property the database table remains "Id, Description". If I create a totally new class and past in the Customer fields it will create the table correctly the first time and again any changes dont appear to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First off all, you should try to figure out if subsonic detects your class definition changes properly.
  This code should give you a overview of the statements subsonic want's to execute.

  ```
  var migrator=new SubSonic.Schema.Migrator(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
  var provider=ProviderFactory.GetProvider("CustomerTest");
  string[] commands=migrator.MigrateFromModel<Customer>(provider);
  ```

  commands should contain all changes subsonic wants to make to your database.
  You can execute these commands by yourself with:
      BatchQuery query = new BatchQuery(provider);
      foreach(var s in commands)
          query.QueueForTransaction(new QueryCommand(s.Trim(), provider));

  ```
  //pop the transaction
  query.ExecuteTransaction();
  ```

  (code taken from http://subsonicproject.com/docs/3.0_Migrations).
  That said, I suppose commands will be empty in your case.
  In that case that could be caused by a statement that is not implemented by the provider you are using (SqlServer/MySQL/SQLite/Oracle). Maybe you should download the SubSonic source and step into the `migrator.MigrateFromModel(...)` method to see what happens.
- Another possible cause (if you use MySQL) could be that your information schema is not up to date. I encountered this problem a while ago. After changing my database and regenerating the DAL with SubSonic 2, my generated code didn't change.
  I figured out that the mysql information schema (and subsonic does queries on the information schema) hadn't changed yet.
  I solved this by executing `FLUSH TABLES` which caused the information scheme to reload. I don't know if that's a bug in mysql or desired behaviour but you should try FLUSH TABLES first.